# Access to a variable from another script of the module type

Tags: javascript, html

How do I access variables from the first script in the second script — in this case, `map`?

I can’t do this in a single script because:

- The first script must be of the `module` type; without it, `import` does not work.
- The second script cannot be of the `module` type, because the function inside must be visible in HTML. (The functions in the module script are not visible.)

Map loading script:

```html
<script type="module">
    import { Map, NavigationControl, Marker, LngLatBounds } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/maplibre-gl';

    var map = new Map({
        container: 'map',
        center: [ myLatLng.lng, myLatLng.lat ],
        zoom: 13
    });
</script>
```

Another script in the same file:

```html
<script>
    function setReaction(reactionNumber) {
        // code
    }
</script>
```

Comment: _“because the function inside must be visible in HTML”_ — No, they don’t need to be. Using `<script type="module">` in HTML works fine. If you’re trying to do `onclick="setReaction(123)"`, that’s bad practice. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 4):

`script` with a `type=module` are "incapsulated" and all variable declarations are not assigned automatically to the `Window` object.

You can assign it by your self,

```
<script type="module">
    import { Map, NavigationControl, Marker, LngLatBounds } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/maplibre-gl';

    window.map = new Map({
        container: 'map',
        center: [myLatLng.lng, myLatLng.lat],
        zoom: 13
    });
</script>
```

But, pay attention that the browser is not assuring any thing between scripts `type=module` which uses `import` and other ones, this means that in your case you need to "wait" till the remote import finishes and then run your code which is depended on the import result.

In the example below, I've used the `import()` syntax which returns a `Promise`, this Promise I assign to be on the global Window object, and you function should use it.

```html
<button onclick="checkMap()" type="button">Test</button>

<div id='map'></div>
<script type="module">

window.mapResolver = import('https://cdn.skypack.dev/maplibre-gl').then(
  ({ Map, NavigationControl, Marker, LngLatBounds }) => {
    var map = new Map({ container: 'map', center: [0, 0], zoom: 13 });

    return map;
  }
);

</script>

<script>
  function checkMap() {
    window.mapResolver.then((map) => {
      console.log(map)
    })
  }
</script>
```